# Detecting the appearance of the options menu (onPrepareOptionsMenu not the answer?)

Tags: java, android

I wanted the do_physics() routines of my game app to freeze when the user presses the menu button and an options menu appears. I can then unfreeze when the menu disappears. I did this by freezing within onPrepareOptionsMenu(). It all appeared to work fine until I noticed that it is possible to cause onPrepareOptionsMenu() to be called by touching the menu button but then slide your finger off the button onto the main display screen in such a way that the menu never appears. This then leaves my game frozen. Presumably there must be some alternative place to do my freezing, something like onReallyPuttingMenuUpNow() or some such.

My testing was on a Nexus S with Android 2.3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much experimentation, onCreateOptionsMenu() appears to be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure , but this might work -

Public boolean onMenuOpened (int featureId, Menu menu) -> Freeze it ;

onoptionsmenuclosed or onbackpressed -> unfreeze it